# Output not as expected when programs ran

Tags: python

I have this program I coded where a computer guesses a random number, but the output isn't as expected with the assignmets output.

```
import random
import math

smaller = int(input("Enter the smaller number: "))
larger = int(input("Enter the larger number: "))

count = 0  

print()    
while True: 
    count += 1
    myNumber = (smaller + larger)/2
    print("%d %d" %(smaller, larger))
    print('Your number is %d' % myNumber) 
    choice = input('Enter =, <, or >:') 
    if choice == '=': 
        print("Hooray, I've got it in %d tries" % count) 
        break 
    elif smaller == larger:        
        print("I'm out of guesses, and you cheated") 
        break 
    elif choice == '<': 
        larger = myNumber - 1    
    else: 
        smaller = myNumber + 1
```

Comment: what's the expected output and what's the current output?

Comment: Expected: 0 10
Your number is 5
Enter =, <, or >: <
0 4
Your number is 2
Enter =, <, or >: >
3 4
Your number is 3

Comment: Actual: 0 10
Your number is 5
Enter =, <, or >:<
6 10
Your number is 8
Enter =, <, or >:>
9 10
Your number is 9

Comment: Seems like each iteration of the while loop is accumulating previous information and figuring into the next result, but I'm unsure.

Comment: It’s not directly related to your issue, but why are you using the old %-style string formatting?

Comment: I checked out an older book from out local library and trying to self teach.

Comment: yeah % would be the old python way of formatting strings, you might want to look into python's fstrings
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems to work.
Are you sure when testing you didn't introduce a weird character in your input? like '< ' (with the space)?
Something you could do would be to do input validation before checking the case and do something else if you detect the character is wrong.

Comment: I've made some changes and it's working thus far, until I try this.

Comment: Enter the smaller number: Enter the larger number: 
0 50
Your number is 25
Enter =, <, or >:0 24
Your number is 12
Enter =, <, or >:0 11
Your number is 5
Enter =, <, or >:0 4
Your number is 2
Enter =, <, or >:0 1
Your number is 0
Enter =, <, or >:1 1
Your number is 1
Enter =, <, or >:2 1
Your number is 1
Enter =, <, or >:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guess.py", line 15, in <module>
    choice = input('Enter =, <, or >:') 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: without your code changes, not sure I can help you ;)

Comment: I didn't change any code, which is odd. Before it was getting the results I posted, then it didn't. The last step for this assignment says, Test for 0-50, when 1 is picked then switched when correctly guessed. When I run the program and perform the entries 0
50
<
<
<
<
>
> then I get the error. This past is suppose to give the cheating message, but doesn't

Comment: It's as if the way I wrote the code, there's no way for the "I'm out of guesses message to pop up.

Comment: made the change here:  elif smaller > larger:        
        print("I'm out of guesses, and you cheated") from                                                                                     elif smaller == larger:        
        print("I'm out of guesses, and you cheated") and it worked

Comment: @WillMcKenzie - You should update your question to be a minimal reproducible example consisting of (complete) code, example input, output that you get, output that you expect.  So that people can reproduce *exactly* what you are doing ... without endless back-and-forth in the comments :-)